# Connecting a document (or any other Office file) to Java to recover password

Tags: java, ms-word, ms-office

I have seen lots of commercial (even free) software that offer to show you the password of a password protected office file.

I assume, this is relatively an easy piece of code to write (for the people who know what they are doing).

My questions are: (Assume we are using Java as programming language, but if you have answers that use another programming language, that's okay)

1. Microsoft stores the passwords in plaintext format? or encrypted?
2. Is brute force used while retrieving the password, or the software just goes and retrieves it from where it's saved inside the file?
3. How do we link the file (`MyFile.docx`) to the program. That is, what libraries are used? Which part of the file we need to go an search for the passwords?

I do not expect detail explanations or basics. Just some keywords and hints where to start. I see this as a good programming exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Java will surely work nice, but give C# a try for Microsoft related stuff.

Now, it's probably neither plaintext nor encrypted: it's surely *hashed*. Take a look at Rainbow lookup tables for that, else: happy brute forcing! There are furthermore a lot of nice tutorials for opening/manipulating docx files out there, take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra) for starters. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gustafbstrom, I will give this a look when Im free. many thanks :)